# Starting nested for loop after external iteration in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two for loops, one inside of the other. I'd like to start the second, internal one, only after the first for loop has run once. I want the first for loop to run once, skip the second for loop, and run the code that is inside the second for loop. Then, after the first iteration, I want the second for loop to start.

I've tried doing the first for loop, then putting an if statement after it that only allows the second loop to begin once the first has run once, but I have to copy all of the code inside the second for loop for this to run anything.

```
option_2 <- 0
for (option in 1:8){
    for (option_2 in 0:4){
   #do something
   }
}
```

I either have to loop through both loops entirely, or I have to copy the entire "#do something," as written:

```
option_2 <- 0
for (option in 1:8){
   if (option == 1){
      # do something
   }else{
   for (option_2 in 0:4){
   #do something
   }
}
```

I would really like to avoid copying the "#do something" twice.

Comment: This problem is a little over-generalized: if you literally had to copy everything in `do something`, then you wouldn't need the first-time separation. If they are very similar but condition solely on the logic of `firsttime`, then write a function that takes relevant data/parameters plus a `firsttime=` argument, and differentiate your function code based on that. Lacking anything more substantial, there's little to go on here.

Comment: The "#do something" code that is inside is exactly the same between each. I suppose that I could make it a function, but I'd just like to see if there is a way to do this without calling the "#do something" a function, because I would have to format the data I need into returns if I had to list it as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using `next`. Notice that the 1st loop ran twice before entering second loop -

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  print("1st loop")
  if(i == 1) next
  for (j in 1:2) {
    print("2nd loop")
  }
}

[1] "1st loop"
[1] "1st loop"
[1] "2nd loop"
[1] "2nd loop"
[1] "1st loop"
[1] "2nd loop"
[1] "2nd loop"
```

Comment: Great, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for!